# JavaScript-assets not being loaded in my grails plugin when used in another application

Tags: grails, plugins, swagger, swagger-ui, assets

I'm developing a grails 4 plugin to display Swagger documentation. Starting the plugin locally works without problem, and the Swagger interface is loaded as expected.

I want to test my plugin locally, so I run the gradle task `publishToMavenLocal` and then declare this as a depencency in my test application using `implementation "swagger.grails4:swagger-grails4:0.1.2"`. So far so good.

When i go to the correct endpoint in my test application, the Swagger interface is however not loaded. When I open the DevTools, I can see that it doesn't load the JavaScript files correctly from my plugin:

[image]

The .gsp view also seem to lack references to my plugin assets when loaded in my test application:

[image]

This view is implemented like this in my plugin code:

```html
<%@ page import="swagger.grails4.SwaggerController" %>
<asset:javascript src="swagger-grails4/swagger-ui-bundle.js" charset="UTF-8"/>
<asset:javascript src="swagger-grails4/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" charset="UTF-8"/>
<asset:stylesheet src="swagger-grails4/swagger-ui.css"/>
<asset:image src="swagger-grails4/favicon-16x16.png"/>
<asset:image src="swagger-grails4/favicon-32x32.png"/>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Swagger UI</title>
    <style>
    html
    {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }

    *,
    *:before,
    *:after
    {
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    body
    {
        margin:0;
        background: #fafafa;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="swagger-ui"></div>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        // Begin Swagger UI call region
        const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
            url: "${createLink(controller: 'swagger', action: 'openApiDocument')}",
            dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
            deepLinking: true,
            validatorUrl: 'none',
            presets: [
                SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
                SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
            ],
            plugins: [
                SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
            ],
            layout: "StandaloneLayout"
        });
        // End Swagger UI call region

        window.ui = ui;
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my plugin I have placed all the assets in the /assets directory under a "namespace" folder, as recommended by the asset-plugin documentation:

[image]

As I said, none of this is a problem if I just run my plugin as a standalone application.